# Как проверить пустая ли строка?

Tags: c#

Пишу игру крестики-нолики на языке `c#` и в нём есть бот который рандомно ставит `0`, а игрок `X`.

Проблема в том, что иногда бот ставит `0` в клетку, где игрок уже поставил `X`.
Каким образом можно исправить?

Comment: `string.IsEmpty(string)`. Это равносильно `(str == null || str.Length == 0)`

Comment: @return `string.IsNullOrEmpty` равносильно `(str == null || str.Length == 0)`

Comment: Ответ: нужно предварительно проверить пустая клетка или нет, если не пустая - то менять координаты и повторять попытку снова.

Comment: @nick_n_a да, забыл) обычно я просто `ReadOnlySpan<char>` использую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У класса `String` есть несколько методов, позволяющих проверить состояние переменной этого типа:

1. `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`

```
string targetString = null;
var result = String.IsNullOrEmpty(targetString);
```

Как правильно написали в коментариях это равносильно:

```
return (targetString == null || targetString.Length == 0);
```

Этот метод предварительно проверяет не null ли ссылка на строку, а потом уже её содержимое (в данном примере `result` равен `true`). Но не всегда содержимое строки для пользователя является "не пустым", поэтому существует метод номер 2:

2. `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

```
string targetString = "       ";
var result = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetString);
```

Вызов этого метода равносилен такой функции:

```
return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(targetString) || targetString.Trim().Length == 0);
```

То есть он проверяет не `null` ли строка, есть ли у неё содержимое и не является ли оно "пустыми" символами.